# Duplicate Removal from Different Rows interchanged columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

1. A SQL Server table that has 4 columns want to remove duplicates based on the link column.
2. if link is the same then remove duplicates based on number and number2 column, which are related to each other.

Table :

```
ID number number2 link
1   1       2       A
2   1       3       A
3   2       1       A
4   3       1       A
5   6       7       B
6   7       6       B
```

Desired Output:

```
ID number number2 link
1   1       2       A
2   1       3       A
5   6       7       B
```

Essentially removing duplicates where number is related to number 2 or vice versa.

I tried pivot using link column but cannot get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is `WITH TIES` in concert with `row_number()`

You may notice that we normalize the pairs in the `Partition By`

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by IIF(number<number2,number,number2),IIF(number>number2,number,number2) order by ID)
```

Returns

```
ID  number  number2 link
1   1       2       A
2   1       3       A
5   6       7       B
```

**Note:**

The `Partition By` can be extended to include LINK.  Not clear if necessary or not.

Comment: I didnt understand the IIFs, rather than just copy and pasting I would like to understand that if that's possible. how you used partition by and IIF to get it can you explain a bit

Comment: @Rishi The IIF() normalize the pairs  so 1,3 is the same as 3,1  both records would be partitioned as if they were both 1,3

Comment: I'm not sure this answer will work of the two number columns are equal.  That could probably be fixed by changing the > in the second IIF to the >=

Comment: @RobertSievers Sure would.  If same, both would default to number2 .  Since the same no issue.

Comment: @RobertSievers To be extra safe, we could add LINK to the partition.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  That's just plain slick.

Comment: @RobertSievers Thanks for the grin  :)

Comment: @Rishi Always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
select id, number, number2, link
from t
where number < number2 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.link = t.link and t2.number = t.number2 and t2.number2 = t.number
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer above looks much more elegant.  But I already this done, so figured I'd post it anyway.
The values are uniquely reversed if they have the same sun and the same absolute value of their difference.  And I like windowing functions.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID,
        Link,
        number + number2 AS column_sum
        ABS(number - number2) AS column_difference
    FROM your_table
)

DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT X.ID FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Link, column_sum, column_difference
                            ORDER BY ID) AS row_num, *
        FROM CTE
    ) AS X
    WHERE X.row_num > 1
)
```